# How to stop submit of all of fields in a div of a form?

Tags: forms, post, html, hidden

I have divided form in to two sections: `sec1` and `sec2`. Each section is part of a div named as `sec1Div` and `sec2Div`. Based upon some selection one of div is **hidden**. But the problem is that still fields in hidden section are submitted. Please suggest a way so that all of fields in a div are not submitted on submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. You can hook a function to the form **`submit`'s event**, or you can **remove the `name` attributes** of the fields inside the hidden div. You can also **disable** the fields, by setting `disabled="disabled"`.

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do those examples.

To disable all fields in the hidden div, you can do something like:

```
function hideDiv(el) {
    $('input', el).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    $(el).hide();
}
```

And, the appropriate show div function:

```
function showDiv(el) {
    $('input', el).each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    $(el).show();
}
```

Please remind that this is just a code example. But you can take the idea from that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because the elements are still within the `form` element. Hiding a `div` using CSS won't change this - they're still present in the DOM.

It would likely be easiest to add a hidden `input` field to each `div` that can be used to identify server side which one you should be processing. You can then simply ignore the data from the hidden form.

If you really must stop the data from being posted, it's a little messy but you could move the hidden `div`'s contents outside of the `form` element so that the fields won't be submitted. If you wanted to display the `div` again, you'd then need to move the fields back in. Depending on how complex your CSS is, this could cause problems in some browsers, so I'd advise using my first suggestion.